# Extract elements from a list and sorting them by length

Tags: python

I have a big file with words on a list i'd like to sort the worlds by length and to put them on different files for example:

```
List1=['example','example1','example12]
```

Output : 
File1 :the words with 7 letters (example)
File2 :the words with 8 letters (example1)
File3 :the words with 9 letters (example12)

Comment: File1, File2, File3?  three different files?

Comment: Do you actually need to sort them by length, then group the sorted list, or you just need to partition them by length, and you thought sorting would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I need to partition them by lenght

Comment: File 1.2.3 are different output files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you actually need any sorting here. You just want to *partition* the words into different files by length. And you can do that on the fly:

```
with open('file1', 'w') as f1, open('file2', 'w') as f2, open('file3', 'w') as f3:
    for entry in List1:
        if len(entry) == 7:
            f1.write(entry)
        elif len(entry) == 8:
            f2.write(entry)
        elif len(entry) == 9:
            f3.write(entry)
```

---

If you're going to have a lot of files (really, 3 is already borderline), I'd consider making this a little more dynamic with a dict instead of an elif chain. For example, this shuttles entries of length 0, 1, 2, …, 9 to files named `file0`, `file1`, …, `file9`:

```
with contextlib.ExitStack as stack:
    lenmap = {i: stack.enter_context(open('file{}'.format(i), 'w')) 
             for i in range(10)}
    for entry in List1:
        f = lenmap.get(len(entry))
        if f:
            f.write(entry)
```

For Python 2.7, you don't have `ExitStack`, so there's no safe way to use an arbitrary number of files in a `with` statement, so we have to use `finally` instead:

```
lenmap = {i: open('file{}'.format(i), 'w') for i in range(10)}
try:
    for entry in List1:
        f = lenmap.get(len(entry))
        if f:
            f.write(entry)
finally:
    for f in lenmap.values():
        f.close()
```

---

I'm guessing you actually want some kind of separator between the words, like `'\n'` or `' '`, but it should be obvious how to add whatever it is you want.

---

One reason you *might* need to sort is if it's just not reasonable to keep all the files open for the entire run (maybe you have an incredibly slow filesystem, and hundreds of files). In that case, you can sort, then group, then do one file at a time:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(List1, key=len), key=len):
    with open('file{}'.format(key), 'w') as f:
        for entry in group:
            f.write(entry)
```

Comment: Actually it's more than 3 , 3 was just an example

Comment: There is 338990 words , if i split it into files i will be able to call only the words with the length needed , i think that would be easier and less consuming for the system ressources

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: I don't understand that comment. What do you mean by "split it into files"? Or "call the words"? Is there something wrong with one of the above solutions, or something you need help with?

Comment: i have an error : with contextlib.ExitStack as stack:
NameError: name 'contextlib' is not defined

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: You need to `import contextlib` before you can use it, just like any other module.

Comment: i hae annother error :       with contextlib.ExitStack as stack:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ExitStack'

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: OK, what version of Python do you have? If you have an old version, you may not have all the newest features. As you can see in the docs, [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) requires 3.3 or later. If you have an older version, there's a backport of 3.3's contextlib on PyPI called [`contextlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contextlib2) that you can install. If your version is too old even for that, then we have to rewrite the code to not use `ExitStack`.

Comment: i'm using 2.7 cause i'm new to scripting

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: Why should "new to scripting" mean "using an older version"? Anyway, I'll edit it to show how to do the next best thing in 2.7.

Comment: Most of books and videos suggest 2.7

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: Most books are old; that's inherent in being books. And someone who's written a book for 2.7 isn't going to recommend that you learn 3.4 and use someone else's book instead of his. :)

Comment: @MedAmineRadi: I really don't know the answer to that. I probably don't even know the best way to learn Python for someone studying programming languages theory in the early 90s, and beyond that my experience isn't very applicable. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List1=['example','example1','example12']

for item in List1:
    fileToWrite = "example{0}".format(len(item))
    with open(fileToWrite, 'a') as fileID:
        fileID.write(item + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short and unpythonic way to do it. Makes use of `collections.defaultdict` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) such that it will create + open files for the word length(s) automatically.

See comments in the code for further explanation.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# default dict that will automatically open/create file
# if it didn't have one open for it yet
class newfile(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = open(str(key)+".txt", 'w')
        return self[key]

# helper to transform a line of text into a list of words
words = lambda line: line.strip().split()

with open("words.txt", 'r') as inputfile:
    # process a word: write it in the correct file
    def procword(filedict, word):
        return filedict[len(word)].write(word+"\n") or filedict
    # process a line in the file: get the words and process them
    def procline(filedict, line):
        return reduce(procword, words(line), filedict)
    # process all lines in the inputfile, starting with an empty length -> file dict
    files = reduce(procline, inputfile, newfile())
    # maybe superfluous, but close all files (it's polite)
    [fd.close() for (_, fd) in files.iteritems()]
```

Comment: I think many people (especially Guido) would object to almost any instance the term "pythonic" and the function "reduce" appearing in the same post. More seriously, it's _definitely_ not pythonic to `map` a function for side-effects instead of for its value. Or to define a named function using `lambda` instead of `def`. Or to use `lambda x: x.close()` instead of just `file.close`—or, even better, using a listcomp so you can write it as an expression instead of a function…

Comment: You _are_ right, so edited some parts, thx. I know the man isn't a fan of reduce but I am. I like the one-line lambda's because it's shorter than the `def` version and I'd like to keep the code as small as possible; don't want to introduce more noise (lines) - especially in these SO posts where space is limited (by design). Note: Initially I didn't even have that `words` helper function but then I'd have to put that inline in the `reduce`, making that line very obnoxious to read.

Comment: And thanks for the `file.close` - I hadn't realized that `file.close(obj)` was the same as `obj.close()` (provided `obj` is-a `file`, ofc.)!

Comment: I don't know why nobody ever teaches unbound methods (what `file.close` is), explains them in tutorials, features them in "cool Python feature of the month" blogs, etc. It would be like nobody ever mentioning operator sectioning in Haskell (I'm guessing you know a bit of Haskell, or something related, based on your style…) so everyone wrote `\x -> x+2` instead of just `(+ 2)`.

Comment: Now that you mention it - I did know about unbound methods, have used them a long time ago. But that it would - naturally - work for library functions too ... just never crossed my mind. Learned something valuable today!

Answer (score -1):

The below script reads source file, divide it to words into list of word sets by length of words then write each element (if it isnot empty) of the list to separate file

```
words=[set() for _ in range(40)]
with open('source.file') as sfile:
    for line in sfile:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            word=word.strip('''\n!"',.:*?;-''')
            if word != '':
                words[len(word)].add(word)
for i in range(len(words)):
    if len(words[i]) != 0:
        fname='te st/file' + str(i)
        with open(fname, 'w') as tfile:
            tfile.write('\n'.join(words[i]))
```